# How can I get a callback to be run even on the event of an error in the python click framework?

Tags: python, python-click

I have a piece of code which I wish to always run at the end of a command execution, regardless of whether the command succeeded or raised an exception. I thought callbacks may be used for this, but it does not seem to be the case. How does one go about achieving this feature?

```py
import click

@click.group()
def cli() -> None:
    """lorem ipsum"""
    print("whatever")


@click.command()
def command1() -> None:
    raise Exception"blah")


@click.command()
def command2() -> None:
    print("hi")


@cli.result_callback()
def process_result(*args: str, **kwargs: int) -> None:
    print("this should always appear")


cli.add_command(command1)
cli.add_command(command2)
```

Comment: Did you review the documentation here: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/exceptions/. The pallets project documentation is very good.

Comment: I have attempted raising a click exception and sadly that does not go to the callback either

Comment: As per the API documentation for [result callback](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/#click.MultiCommand.result_callback): "The result callback is invoked with the return value of the subcommand". In case of an exception there is no return value from a subcommand. The definition of an exception is no return. It does not look like you can use `result_callback` to handle exceptions. You would have to wrap the error as a special return value, or else come up with a different design.

Comment: Wrapping in a special return value is always an option, but unideal as we do not wish to bother with needing to enforce that all the engineers writing subcommands about special decorators/exception wrapping they must always do. Rather, we wish to have a centralized cleanup mechanism guaranteed to always run at the end and has access to the global context.